# Python List not sorting

Tags: python, xml, list, sorting

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('A00.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

for w in root.iter('w'):
    lemma = w.get('hw')
    pos = w.get('pos')
    tag = w.get('c5')
    myList = (w.text + "\t" + lemma + "\t" + pos + "\t" + tag)
    sorted(myList)
    print(myList)
```

The list still prints in iterated order.

I want to sort alphabetically by the first character in each line of the list

```
myList.sort(key = lambda ele : ele[1])
```

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'sort'

So I want to have a list of strings and sort by the first character of each string, but strings are immutable so I have a sort error...

```
for w in root.iter('w'):
    lemma = w.get('hw')
    pos = w.get('pos')
    tag = w.get('c5')
    myList = (w.text + "\t" + lemma + "\t" + pos + "\t" + tag)
    print(myList)
```

Prints (sample):

```
can can VERB    VM0
I   i   PRON    PNP
have    have    VERB    VHB
in  in  PREP    PRP
recent  recent  ADJ AJ0
years   year    SUBST   NN2
edited  edit    VERB    VVD
a   a   ART AT0
self-help   self-help   ADJ AJ0
journal     journal SUBST   NN1
for     for PREP    PRP
people  people  SUBST   NN0
```

Desired:

```
a   a   ART AT0
can can VERB    VM0
edited  edit    VERB    VVD
for     for PREP    PRP
have    have    VERB    VHB
I   i   PRON    PNP
in  in  PREP    PRP
journal     journal SUBST   NN1
people  people  SUBST   NN0
recent  recent  ADJ AJ0
self-help   self-help   ADJ AJ0
years   year    SUBST   NN2
```

Comment: Not a duplicate, the problem here is that the OP is trying to call sort on a `str`.

Answer (score 0):

**Updated Answer:**

Your problem is that you are trying to sort a `str` not a `list`. Strings are not sortable. Maybe you want to do something like this:

```
myList = sorted(list(w.text + "\t" + lemma + "\t" + pos + "\t" + tag))
print(myList)
```

That will give you a sorted list of all of the characters in the string. If you want to concatenate them back into a string, you can use:

```
print(''.join(myList))
```

**Old Answer:**

`sorted` *returns* a sorted list, it does not modify the original list. If you want to sort the list in-place, use the `sort` function:

```
for w in root.iter('w'):
    ...
    myList.sort()
    print(myList)
```

Comment: NameError: name 'sort' is not defined

Comment: @pglove, fixed. It's a function on the list itself. Sorry.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. I keep getting 'sort is not defined'

Comment: @pglove, oh, I see. `myList` is actually a `str`. That's the root problem here.

Comment: yeah, not sure what the problem is though. When I print myList it prints fine, why can't I send those strings to a list and sort by the first character of each string?

Comment: @pglove, see my updated answer. Does that help?

Comment: still baffled. There are hundreds of w values in the xml, each with a text value, and associated attributes for lemma, pos, and tag. Iterated output has four words line. I need to sort the lines alphabetically.

Comment: @pglove, well, that's a different question then. There are probably ways to do this using the XML parsing library instead of writing your own code.

Comment: I recommend either clarifying this question with what you want to accomplish or ask another question.

Comment: sorry and thanks for all the help. I'll try and clarify it :)